# Populate predefined string with dataframe values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a string that should look like this:
**"On 2021-02-08, Buccaneers won against Chiefs in the Super Bowl. MVP was Tom Brady."**

Or, with placeholders,like this:
**"On [date], [team1] [won/lost] against [team2]. MVP was [mvp]"**

With a dataframe looking like

```
date          team1         team2     won    mvp
2021-02-08    Buccaneers    Chiefs    won    Tom Brady
```

Imagine the dataframe populated with all the super bowls.
Now, I would like to have a final column "printString", that inserts the previous columns in the appropriate position.
I could do that with

```
df["printString"] = f'On {df["date"]}, {df["team1"]} {df["won"]} against {df["team2"]} in the Super Bowl. MVP was {df["mvp"]}'
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this? Possibly something where I could write {team1} instead of df["team1"}?

Comment: Your solution seems elegant enough in my opinion, and it already uses `f-strings`, trying to use `team1` instead of `df['team1']` will complexify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) here:

```
func = lambda x: f'On {x["date"]}, {x["team1"]} {x["won"]} against {x["team2"]} in the Super Bowl. MVP was {x["mvp"]}'
df["printString"] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```